# Добавить строку в ключ реестра если эта строка отсутствует

Tags: vbscript, lisp

Здравствуйте Уважаемые программисты!

Есть фрагмент кода на lisp, который переписывает строковое значение ключа реестра "ToolPaletteDir" на значение "ToolPalette;\\server\Палитры":

```
(vl-registry-write (strcat "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\" (vlax-product-key) "\\Profiles\\" (getvar "CPROFILE") "\\StdDirs") "ToolPaletteDir" "ToolPalette;\\\\server\\Палитры")
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью lisp или vbs НЕ переписывать целиком строковое значение ключа "ToolPaletteDir", а проверить в нем наличие подстрок "ToolPalette" и "\\server\Палитры" и если эти (одна из них) строки отсутствуют, то добавить их к существующим подстрокам?

Рабочий код ниже:

```
Dim nanoPRFL, nanoADVR
nanoPRFL = ThisDrawing.GetVariable("cprofile")
nanoADVR = ThisDrawing.GetVariable("acadver")

Dim windowsShell
Dim regValueStart, regValue, newregValue1, newregValue2
Set windowsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
regValueStart = windowsShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Nanosoft\nanoCAD x64\" & nanoADVR & "\Profiles\" & nanoPRFL & "\StdDirs\ToolPaletteDir")

Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.Pattern = "ToolPalette"
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
If UBound(Split(regValueStart, objRegExp.Pattern))=0 Then
  newregValue1 = regValueStart & ";ToolPalette"
  windowsShell.RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Nanosoft\nanoCAD x64\" & nanoADVR & "\Profiles\" & nanoPRFL & "\StdDirs\ToolPaletteDir"), newregValue1, "REG_SZ"
End If

regValue = windowsShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Nanosoft\nanoCAD x64\" & nanoADVR & "\Profiles\" & nanoPRFL & "\StdDirs\ToolPaletteDir")

objRegExp.Pattern = "\\server\Палитры"
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
If UBound(Split(regValue, objRegExp.Pattern))=0 Then
  newregValue2 = regValue & ";\\server\Палитры"
  windowsShell.RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Nanosoft\nanoCAD x64\" & nanoADVR & "\Profiles\" & nanoPRFL & "\StdDirs\ToolPaletteDir"), newregValue2, "REG_SZ"
End If
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что изменить в коде, чтобы выстроить последовательность строк в ключе, например так: строки "ToolPalette" и "\server\Палитры" были всегда последние?

Заранее спасибо!